# Parameter LocalIpv4Cidr fails its validation function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-virtual-private-gateway, amazon-site-to-site-vpn

Trying to create second Site-to-Site VPN connection, but for some reason can't update `Local IPv4 network CIDR` property and static routes as well. Unfortunately, can't find any information about errors.
Local IP Cidr for both Site-to-Site VPN connections don't overlap.
Please advice.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my IP address should end with `0` (10.160.5.`0`/25), because `0` is also included in /25 range